# (Ubuntu server 20.04) MySQL DB failing to reinstall

Tags: server, mysql, database, reinstall

I tried to make a login system but inexperienced in servers and backend as I am, I followed two tutorials with different login credentials for the DB and now I've locked myself out. The first password for root@localhost didn't work. My simpliest solution was to uninstall the DB as it wasn't in use yet and didn't have any connections (I believe). When I was to reinstall it, parts of the package were lost and it failed to fetch stuff from ubuntu archives.
I think I screwed up, but is it that hard to install a DB?
If I need to wipe it all over again I can do that, there are three files in use now which are easily replacable.
So, what do you recommend?

Comment: We need more information. What commands did you run? How did you attempt to install it? What error messages did you get? [Edit] your question to add as much information as possible.

Comment: It’s not hard after doing it a hundred times, but starting from zero often has a very steep learning curve. After uninstalling MySQL, be sure to delete the `/var/lib/mysql` directory as well, otherwise reinstallation will just pick up the existing database files and use them again.

Comment: @matigo So do you think I should delete the MySQL service once again and make sure everything is gone before reinstalling?

Comment: That would most likely be the simplest way forward, yes. Clear out MySQL completely, then perform the 3-step install to get the database engine back on your machine.